# C++ function using a kind of bitwise: I'll get duplicated values?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

this is my C++ function that uses a kind of bitwise:

```
int genkey(const unsigned char a,const char b,const char c )
{
    int val=0;
    unsigned char *p= reinterpret_cast <unsigned char *>(&val);
    p[0]=a;
    char *q= reinterpret_cast <char *>(&val);
    q[1]=b;
    q[2]=c;
    return val;
}
```

I'm using that for generating keys (unique value for object).

The range of the values that can be passed to the function are: for a parameter => [0..255], for b parameter => [0..127] and for c parameter => [0..127].

Assume that the function can be called only once with the same three arguments values. For example there will be only one call with values (10, 0, 0).

Does function return duplicated values?

Thanks.

Comment: I have retagged your question from "c" to "c++" because your example uses C++ style casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your code will give different results on different architectures.* Maybe that doesn't matter, of course.

This is a portable equivalent:

```
return ((((int) a << 8) + b) << 8) + c;
```

Or this:

```
return ((((int) a * 256) + b) * 256) + c;
```

Comment: Yes, different results aren't important for me. My goal is to obtain unique values. For the first version do you mean: return ((((unsigned int) a << 8) + b) << 8) + c; ? Warning, return value must be int and not unsigned int.

Comment: Thanks, in the first version c parameter is missed... Correct is this: return ((((int) a << 8) + b) << 8) + c;
Right?

Answer (score 7):

Your function probably returns unique values for each unique set of input values (assuming your `int` is at least 24 bits wide). However, a better way to write this might be:

```
int genkey(const unsigned char a,const char b,const char c )
{
    return a
         | (static_cast<unsigned char>(b) << 8)
         | (static_cast<unsigned char>(c) << 16);
}
```

This combines three 8-bit values into a single 24-bit value without using hard-to-read pointer manipulation.

Note that I have taken care to cast the `char` values (which might be `signed char` depending on your compiler settings) to `unsigned char` before shifting them. The reason is that shifting will first promote the value to a signed `int`, which may involve sign extension. You won't want that.

Comment: Such a function could well be converted into a macro since half of its time is spent in calling the function and copying the parameters.

Comment: Indeed. In C++ it is probably better defined as an `inline` function.

Answer (score 0):

On any reasonable machine that I can think of unique input values will produce a unique result.